# Fixing Carbon Fiber

Tags: repair

I have a Cervélo S2 and absolutely love my bike. It has been rock solid. Unfortunately, I had a bad case of chain suck when my chain fell off my chain ring right when I was grinding up a hill. The damage left a little hole with exposed fibers right inside of my chain rings. I doubt Cervélo would warranty it, though that would be awesome.

What about repairs? Has there been any new advancements with carbon fiber repairs? I had similar damage on a mountain bike and just put an epoxy over the hole to keep moisture out. The repair held and I have ridden my MTB without problems since.

Also, I have to repair a pair of Sidi's too.

Comment: If it's just a few exposed fibers, I'd coat the "wound" with a little epoxy and call it good.

Comment: Cervelo has a very good reputation for warranty stuff. Send them an email, it's free to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite common belief, carbon is repairable. [Calfee Design](http://www.calfeedesign.com/repair/) is likely the best known company for this. It's not cheap, but it's not as expensive as a new frame.

Comment: Check hot tubes.com I've seen their work it is excellent. I believe they are also authorized by Cervelo to do paint schemes with original graphics.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the damage is considerable, I doubt that you'd need carbon fiber cloth in addition to the epoxy. This person gives some detailed photos of his DIY repair, http://www.instructables.com/id/Repairing-a-Carbon-Fiber-Bicycle-Frame/step47/null/

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. We prefer answer posts on this site to be self contained. While your post theoretically answers the question, it would be better if you provided a summary of the content contained in the link that you provided.